# Lanzamiento de excepciones

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola a tod@s tengo el siguiente código el cual toma como parámetro un número entero positivo. Si el parámetro que se le pasa tiene el tipo y valor adecuado, la función pedirá al usuario tantos números como indica el valor del parámetro y formará con ellos una lista, con los elemnentos introducidos en orden. En caso de que el usuario se equivoque al introducir los valores la función tratará la excepción que se produzca y continuará pidiendo números al usuario hasta que tenga todos los que necesita.

**Mi problema es que no se como tratar que la lista sea vacía:**

```
def example(number):
    lista = []
    if type(number) != int:     
        raise TypeError("Error de tipo TypeError")
    elif number < 0:
        raise ValueError("Error de tipo ValueError")
    if len(lista) == 0:      
        raise ValueError    
    while number:
        try:
            data = int(input("Data: "))
        except ValueError: 
            pass        
        else:
            lista.append(data)
            number -= 1
    return lista

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(example(5)) # Señala el numero de elementos que va a tener la lista
```

Comment: Hola ¿Con "no se como tratar que la lista sea vacía" te refieres a que si el usuario ingresa mal los 5 enteros (o los que se pidan) retorne una lista vacía? Si es eso basta con que saques `number -= 1` del `else` y lo coloques al final del `while` al mismo nivel que el `try`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable lista sólo puede acabar vacía si el parámetro numero es igual a cero. Para ello simplemente lo protegemos cambiando:

- Antes: if number < 0
- Ahora: if number <= 0

Otros cambios:

- He añadido comentarios mas entendibles por un usuario a los errores generados.
- He dejado las 2 condiciones con if (elif no es necesario)

```
def example(number):
    lista = []
    if type(number) != int:
        raise TypeError("Número debe de ser entero")
    if number <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Número debe de ser mayor que cero")
    while number:
        try:
            data = int(input("Data: "))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            lista.append(data)
            number -= 1
    return lista

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(example(5)) # Señala el numero de elementos que va a tener la lista
```

Una pequeña refactorización adicional (aplicando la regla de intentar no mezclar distintas tareas en una misma función) sería la siguiente:

- Dejar en example la tarea de realizar las comprobaciones
- y sacar a otra función (get_data) la tarea de obtención de datos. En este caso devuelvo el valor con yield, para que sea una función generadora y poder iterar sobre la función.
- Uniendo ambas mediante una lista por comprensión que itera sobre la función anterior

```
def example(number):
    if type(number) != int:
        raise TypeError("Número debe de ser entero")
    if number <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Número debe de ser mayor que cero")
    lista = [x for x in get_data(number)]
    return lista


def get_data(number):
    while number:
        try:
            data = int(input("Data: "))
            number -= 1
            yield data
        except ValueError:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(example(5))  # Señala el numero de elementos que va a tener la lista
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda